# Access denied connecting to a share using Windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, windows-10

On a Windows 2012 R2 computer a folder is shared, let us call it 'SharedFolder'. A Group called 'AccessSharedFolder' containing me has Read-Access to this folder on NTFS Level. Shared Level is: Everyone Full Control.

Now when trying to connect from my Windows 10, v1709 Computer this share, I get an "access denied". Running

> msdt.exe /id NetworkDiagnosticsFileShare

does not provide a clue.

Now when accessing the same shared folder from a Windows Server 2008 R2 computer it works.

Accessing other folders on the same Windows 2012 R2 Computer works from Windows 10 client. Adding other users in the same user group also fails on their Windows 10 clients.

What can be done to have this fixed?

Comment: If you browse to \\servername do you see the shares from the Windows 10 clients?

Comment: Question on the network level - could any firewalls cause a problem? Are the clients/servers in different subnets? Are all devices in a domain/in the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can only give permissions on [Security Groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups#about-active-directory-groups), double check that you haven't created a Distribution Group (you can see that in the group's properties, under "Group type").

Then, don't forget that you must logoff and logon again on the client before the group membership is effective. If you logon as User1 on PC1, and then you add User1 to Group1 in Active Directory, you have to logoff/logon again on PC1 with User1 before the group membership is effective.

Take a look at the "Effective Access" tab in the advanced Security Options of the folder, you will be able to choose a username and ask Windows to check if the user has access or not, and eventually why the access is denied.